# Problem mounting NTFS disks

Tags: mount, raspbian, fdisk

I had initially gotten good results in using `/etc/fstab` to specify mounting points for my hard disks. But after meddling around with folder permissions, my disks refused to mount.

What I was doing:

- Using `chown` to give permissions to Transmission (didn't get it to work anyway)

What happened:

- After one of many reboots, my disks stopped being mounted.
- `fstab -l` and `blkid` did not show my 2 disks

Out of curiosity, I commented out the lines in `/etc/fstab`, and to my surprise, the two above steps showed the disks (not auto-mounted), and I could successfully mount them.

My problem:

- I need to assign specific permissions to the disks, as I'm trying to use one of them for owncloud
- Thus, to my understanding, the disks need to be added to the `/etc/fstab` file to work

The 2 pertinent lines in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID="4A58B8EF58B8DB41" /media/pi/EdwinHDD1     ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions, 0 0
UUID="BEEAEC08EAEBBB33" /media/pi/MediaHDD      ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions, 0 0
```

I'm pretty much at my wits end. Any advice please?

My system:

> Distributor ID: Raspbian
>
> Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
>
> Release:        8.0
>
> Codename:       jessie

Comment: Better practice than using chown to change the owner might be to add the relevant account/service to a group with ownership of the folder. (For instance, you need to be a member of the cdrom group to burn CDs.)

Comment: OwnCloud needs have full ownership of the folder though, and therein lies my problem